# jquery mobile dialog does not show

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi I have the following page

```php
<div data-role="page" id="blockedusers">

        <?php
        include 'homeheader.php';
        ?>

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#" id="logoutbutton"  data-role="button" data-icon="home">Log Uit</a>
            <h1>Blocklijst</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="grid_outer" id="grid_outer_blocklist" style="width: 295px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <div class="grid_inner" id="grid_inner_blocklist">
                    <h2 class="h2_header">Geblokkeerde gebruikers</h2>
                    <?php
                    show_blocked_users($blockedusers);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">terug</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Blocklijst</h4>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="dialog" id="confirmbox">
        <div data-role="header" data-icon="false">
            <h1>Bevestig</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <h3 id="confirmMsg">Bevestig</h3>

            <br>

            <center>
                <a href="#" class="btnConfirmYes" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#" class="btnConfirmNo" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">No</a>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I have the following javascript in an external js file

```js
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blockedusers', function() {

alert('pagebeforeshow blockedusers');

$('[id=unblocklink]').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var userid = $(this).attr('userid');

    alert('unblocklink clicked userid ' + userid);

    showConfirm("Weet je zeker dat je deze gebruiker wilt deblokkeren?", function() {

        $.ajax({
            async : false,
            url : "../php/process_unblock_user.php?userid=" + userid,
            success : function(data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    // in case of error
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    alert("Gebruiker gedeblokkeerd!");
                    window.location.reload(true);

                }
            }
        });
    });

});

// confirm dialog
function showConfirm(msg, callback) {

    alert('showing dialog1');

    $("#confirmMsg").text(msg);
    $("#confirmbox .btnConfirmYes").on("click.confirmbox", function() {
        $("#confirmbox").dialog("close");
        callback();
    });

    $("#confirmbox .btnConfirmNo").off("click.confirmbox", function(r) {
    });

    alert('showing dialog2');

    $.mobile.changePage('#confirmbox', {
        allowSamePageTransition : true
    });

}

});
```

The problem is, the confirmdialog never shows (???). I added the javascript on the same page but then I have issues with the unblocklink.

Comment: if you call it by only using `$.mobile.changePage('#confirmbox')` without the code before, does it work?

Comment: @omar, no only after I hard refresh the page the confirmbox shows when I click the unblocklink.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution to fix the issue:

When navigating to the blockedusers page from the home page, I need to do it the following way:

```
$('#blockedusers').click(function(e) {
window.location.href = "blockedusers.php";
});
```

Only then the confirmbox is available in the DOM.

This does not work:

```
$.mobile.changePage('blockedusers.php');
```

Hope this solution helps more people out.